# Visual studio autoexp.dat alternative?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, debuggervisualizer

Custom debug visualization in visual studio:

Is there any way to do it per project instead of editing the "global" autoexp.dat?

Would be nice if it tagged along when changing workstation..

Answer (score 2):

No: per-project (or per-user) visualizers in Visual Studio 2010 (C++ native) are not possible. Visual Studio 2012 added this feature; it is [based on "natvis" XML files](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2012/07/12/10329460.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Rather old question, but lets give my cent:

For VS2008 SP1 and VS2010 you have the alternative to use your custom file, instead of invasively edit the native autoexp.dat file using the `_vcee_autoexp` environment variable.

Credit to: https://vtk.org/Wiki/ITK/Debug_Visualizers_for_Visual_Studio

**Note:** I have not tried, but maybe using a relative path VS loads it based on the solution folder. Alternatively I would also try using multiple path separated with semicolons. Just give it a try.